# Spring Batch Performance Improvement for a complex job

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, postgresql, spring-batch

I've a Spring Batch Job that runs on a daily basis and has around 100k records to process. I've configured my batch as below.

**ItemReader** : I've used ***JdbcCursorItemReader*** that reads data from a single table(This table has all the source records). **Chunk** size is **1000**

**ItemProcessor** : Here I've added logic to perform validation for every record. Validation includes checking the data for its correctness and once validations are complete I've to verify **few more tables**(for this record).

**ItemWriter** : Here I've updated final tables based on the validation results.(This is a bulk operation and I've used **JdbcTemplate.batchUpdate** for faster processing).

***Results :***
For processing 104000 records job took around **140 min**. Since this is run on a daily basis and many other jobs are running parallely in production I want to enhance the performance of this batch.

Can someone suggest a better way to enhance this batch? (I've tried multithreaded approach provided by spring batch using taskexecutor in step config but I've got some cursor issues in reader as below)

```
**Caused by: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: Unexpected cursor position change.
at org.springframework.batch.item.database.AbstractCursorItemReader.verifyCursorPosition(AbstractCursorItemReader.java:368)
at org.springframework.batch.item.database.AbstractCursorItemReader.doRead(AbstractCursorItemReader.java:452)
at org.springframework.batch.item.support.AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.read(AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.java:88)
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider.doRead(SimpleChunkProvider.java:91)
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.FaultTolerantChunkProvider.read(FaultTolerantChunkProvider.java:87)**
```

[Screenshot of CPU sample inside ItemProcessor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zgUJt.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use **JVisualVm** to monitor the bottlenecks inside your application. 
Since you said "for processing 104000 records job took around 140 min", you will get better insights of where you are getting performance hits.

[VisualVm tutorial](https://engineering.talkdesk.com/ninjas-guide-to-getting-started-with-visualvm-f8bff061f7e7)

Open visualvm connect your application => sampler  => cpu => CPU Samples.
Take snapshot at various times and analyse where is it taking much time. By checking this only you will get enough data for optimisation.

Note: JvisualVm comes under oracle jdk 8 distribution. you can simply type jvisualvm on command prompt/terminal. if not download from [here](https://visualvm.github.io/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply Binu. I've did sampling with 1000 records. Job run time is around 110 secs. But when I sampled the CPU multiple times, I found that inside processor, for every record king 3 different fetch calls which is taking around 80% of CPU time inside processor. I'll make a change to use jdbcTemplate for the fetch instead of namedJdbcTemplate. Attaching the screenshot of the sample below.